# Grepl function to match exact phrases in R

Tags: r, match, keyword, grepl

I am working on a dataset that contains a text column. Each row of the text column has multiple sentences. I am trying to use a list of keywords to extract rows of the dataframe that match exactly with the list of words (lowercase and uppercase both). However, when I use grepl function and provide a list of keywords separated by |, my dataset somehow returns 5,000 observations. I tried to then use \b before and after each keyword, so my dataset provides a different number of observations. My keywords also contain 2 separate words to be read together. For instance -

When I use the follwing code, my dataset returns 5007 rows.

```r
data_trd_tar_for <- data_trd_tar_for[grepl("\\bSection 201\\b|\\bSec. 201\\b|\\bSec 201\\b|\\bsolar\\b|\\bsolar panels\\b|\\bwashers\\b|\\bwasher machines\\b|\\bwashing machines\\b|
                              \\b201 investigation\\b|\\bSection 301\\b|\\bSec. 301\\b|\\bSec 301\\b|\\b301 investigation\\b|\\bSection 232\\b|\\bSec. 232\\b|\\bSec 232\\b|\\bsteel\\b|\\baluminium\\b|\\b232 investigation\\b|
                              \\bChina\\b|\\bChinese\\b|\\bChina IPR\\b", ignore.case=TRUE, 
                                          data_trd_tar_for$issue_text),]
```

When I use the following code, my dataset returns 5020 obs

```r
data_trd_tar_for <- data_trd_tar_for[grepl("Section 201|Sec. 201|Sec 201|solar|solar panels|washers|washer machines|washing machines|201 investigation|Section 301|Sec. 301|Sec 301|301 investigation|Section 232|Sec. 232|Sec 232|steel|aluminium|232 investigation|China|Chinese|China IPR", ignore.case=TRUE, data_trd_tar_for$issue_text),]
```

Not sure, what exactly is each code is picking and throwing in output. Please guide me on this issue. I am new to R and trying different codes to make it work for my research. Thanks.

Preety

Comment: The code is keeping all rows of your data that matches in the `issue_text` column any one (or more) of the regex patterns you have separated by `|`. I'm not sure what more you think we can explain to you with the information you have provided...

Comment: Perhaps you could construct a reproducible example for a simpler version of the same problem? Share 5 rows of input data, a simple regex pattern with 2 or 3 phrases to match, and your expected output. That's something we can understand and explain. We generally look for **minimal reproducible examples** as the mark of an answerable question - and that needs to include a little bit of sample input.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I am confused if | is picking solar and solar panels both? Also, what is \\b doing if I add it before and after each word? Does grepl pick exact words such as in the case of sec. 201? Full stop in between two words, does it create any issue? 
Say my text is txt <- (“all in section 201 and solar modules”, “sec. 232 is steel”, sec investigations”, “201 investigations”, “sec. 301 is flawed”) So, if I use grepl with my keyword list on this text, how to do that? Also, what difference will using | and \\b make to the output? Hope this clarifies my question. Thanks.

Comment: You should look for an introduction to regex rather than post a complicated regex pattern and ask how it work. `|` means "or". `\\b` is a word boundary - they are not related at all. `.` is  special character in regex, matching anything. It seems like you most of your basic assumptions about regex are incorrect, so a tutorial with simple examples would be a better place to start than complex sentences with a gigantic 390 character pattern! Once you've read about the basics, head over to regex101.com to test out your understanding.

Comment: Stack Overflow is geared towards questions with relatively short answers. If you understand everything *except* for one concept like `\\b` or `|` or `.` or whether `grepl` does exact matching, that would make an decent question that we could answer. But understanding *none* of those concepts makes your question too big for Stack Overflow.